# Resizing tree/window in R

Tags: r, tree, resize

This has been addressed multiple times online regarding plots, but not trees. I've plotted a classification tree in which the labels/text seem not to fit the plot window:

```
xtree <- rpart(Event ~ ACTIVITY_X + ACTIVITY_Y + ACTIVITY_Z, data = train, method = "class", parms = list(split = "information"))

plot(xtree)
text(xtree)
summary(xtree)
```

Here's a picture of the tree itself, as you see some of the text is cut. Maybe I can just decrease the size of the text to make it fit?

[image]

Hope this is a relevant question!

Comment: Please use `dput(xtree)` to create a printable version of your tree data and paste it into your question so that we can work with your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `par` to adjust the scale using `cex`.  I don't have your data, but this should work.

```
xtree <- rpart(Event ~ ACTIVITY_X + ACTIVITY_Y + ACTIVITY_Z, data = train, method = "class", parms = list(split = "information"))

par(cex = .5)
plot(xtree)
text(xtree)
summary(xtree)
```

You can adjust `cex` to make it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use

> text(my.tree, use.n=T, xpd=NA)

where `xpd` is the parameter to ["par"](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/par) to avoid clipping outside the plot region.  If xpd=FALSE, all plotting is clipped to the plot region, if TRUE, all plotting is clipped to the figure region, and if NA, all plotting is clipped to the device region.